# how to optimize cuda program for get better performance?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I write matlab program(cuda) for generate key.

how to optimize cuda program for get better performance?

Comment: If you provided more details, it might be easier to answer the question.

Comment: i think this question is very unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to spend some time learning the CUDA programming tools and architecture. There is a lot of good info at [developer.nvidia.com](http://developer.nvidia.com) and they have active and helpful forums there for CUDA developers - a great place for noobs to get up to speed on CUDA development.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of training material on the [NVIDIA website](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpucomputing.html), specifically checkout the [training page](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_training.html) and sign up for at least one of the free [online seminars](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/gpu_computing_online.html) (pre-recorded sessions also available, same link).

Once you've got started, post code either on the [NVIDIA CUDA forums](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showforum=62) or here on StackOverflow and the community will likely help out, but you'll need more specific questions to get more specific answers!

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, use a parallel algorithm
- Tune memory access pattern (coalesce reads,etc)
- Use textures, shared memory
- Tune core occupancy (check cuda excel spreadsheet)
- use streams

You should read the programming guide and best practices. Programming Gems are also very good.